# Facebook Graph Api manage_pages permission won't work in dev mode

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I am developping a nodeJs application, where I will post to a Facebook page.
I read that in dev mode, you have all the permissions available.
but I keep getting this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBTIR.png)

So my question is, should I request a manage_pages permission even though I am in dev mode?

Thank you so much for helping me, I'm still a beginner and I'm quiet lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop using `manage_pages` permission as it was deprecated and replaced by 6 different permissions - you can read the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version7.0) to find out which permission you should request.